# shell script nested loop to copy files

Tags: bash, shell

```
for i in 2 4 8 16
do
         for j in 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000
         do
                 cp foo.c bar_$i_$j.c
         done
done
```

I have this nested loop. The output I expected is

```
bar_2_100.c
bar_2_1000.c
bar_2_10000.c
bar_2_100000.c
bar_2_1000000c.
bar_4_100.c
bar_4_1000.c
bar_4_10000.c
bar_4_100000.c
bar_4_1000000c.
...
```

But I didn't get `$i` part of loop.
My output is

```
bar_100.c
bar_1000.c
```

and so on.
How can I copy the similar name by using nested loop in shell script?

Comment: Need to tell where the variable name ends. replace with the following command, cp foo.c "bar_${i}_$j.c"